# Is $\int_{-a}^{a}f(x)\:\:dx=\int_0^a [f(x)+f(-x)]dx$ for any continuous function $f(x)?$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, functional-analysis

We know that $$\int_{-a}^{a}f(x)\:\:dx$$ $$=0$$ if $f(x)$ is odd and $$2\int_0^a f(x)\:\: dx$$ if $f(x)$ is even. So based on this hypothesis can we say that

> $$\int_{-a}^{a}f(x)\:\:dx=\int_0^a [f(x)+f(-x)]dx$$ for any continuous function $f(x)?$

Comment: yes of course it's true...

Comment: It can be verified by splitting the integral on the LHS and perform substitution

Comment: It's true even without your hypothesis, since not all functions are even or odd: most are neither.

Comment: Please use more descriptive titles.

Comment: @Shaun noted.....btw i I edited the title of this question

Comment: @TravorLZH actually I'm a beginner in this area ...so it'll be really helpful for me if you elaborate

Comment: I've edited it to a better, more descriptive one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several ways to show this. For instance, every continuous function can be written as the sum of an odd and an even function:

$$f(x) = \frac{f(x)-f(-x)}{2}+\frac{f(x)+f(-x)}{2}.$$

Therefore by the properties you have stated

$$\int_{-a}^{a}f(x) \ dx = 2\int_{0}^{a}\frac{f(x)+f(-x)}{2} \ dx = \int_{0}^{a}[f(x)+f(-x)] \ dx.$$

Answer (score 2):

$$I=\int_{-a}^{a} f(x) dx=\int_{-a}^{0} f(x) dx+\int_{0}^{a} f(x) dx$$
In the first one take $x=-x'$ to write
$$I=-\int_{a}^{0} f(-x') dx'+\int_{0}^{a} f(x) dx$$
$$\implies I=\int_{0}^{a} f(-x') dx'+\int_{0}^{a} f(x) dx$$
Or
$$\implies I=\int_{0}^{a} f(-x) dx.+\int_{0}^{a} f(x) dx$$
$$\implies I=\int_{0}^{a} [f(-x)+f(x)]~ dx$$